# Why can a file which is open in a stream not be renamed?

Tags: c#, .net

With the following piece of code, i read a file and keep the stream open.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\test1.txt", FileMode.Open);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If i now try to rename this file, the message "File in use" is shown. 
[image: file in use]

It looks like the rename of a file should be possible(on os level), even if it is in use: [Why does rename a loaded .net assembly work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774099/why-does-rename-a-loaded-net-assembly-work)

Why can't a file be renamed when it is loaded in a stream by .net?

Comment: Because streams have handles to the files, assemblies are loaded into memory and the location becomes irrelevant (post-discovery).

Comment: But as far as i did understand from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774099/why-does-rename-a-loaded-net-assembly-work, the filename should not matter anyway. Why does it matter if a handle to the file exist? It would change only directory entries.

Comment: @GrantThomas And what happens when the assembly is loaded into the `AppDomain`. Will you able to delete the assembly file?

Answer (score 2):

About assemblies, .NET should open the assembly using something like `FileShare.ReadWrite` so, even if it's loaded into the domain, any other process can write or rename the whole file.

AFAIK, .NET doesn't have a managed `FileShare` enum value for allowing or disallowing renaming the file share (something like `FileShare.Rename`), but Win32 should have thus assembly loading would be creating the file stream with a mask like `FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Rename` (`FileShare.Delete` includes renaming but also removing the whole file...).

For demonstrating this, I've tried the following code:

```
    FileStream a = File.Open(@"C:\blah.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    a.Dispose();
```

While the file stream was opened and until it's disposed, I couldn't delete the whole file but I could rename it.

Note that assemblies are loaded into the `AppDomain` when they're needed, meaning that maybe you can write, delete or rename an assembly because it's not loaded yet.

Try to delete an assembly already loaded into the `AppDomain`: you can't (I've tried myself just now, the test code runs in a console app and I couldn't remove the executable while running it). Now try to rename it: it works.

### Summary

It's all about how a file is opened and which file mask configuration was used when the file stream was opened: **this is why your file can't be renamed but you can rename an already loaded assembly**.

Modify your code like the next one and you'll be able to rename the whole file (even delete it!):

```
    FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@"C:\temp\test1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Does the downvoter has any reason to downvote? I believe that's a reasonable answer for the OP. It's not about diposing or not disposing streams but why some opened streams allow renaming a file and other no.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `FileStream` you don't load it's data to the memory.
when you are seeking the stream, the file content is still read from the disk - a good thing to do when you need to read big files.

If all you want to do is to load the whole content to memory you can use `File.ReadAllBytes`.
You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx.

Note: If you want to use a stream and not a byte array, you can use `MemoryStream` and pass the read file content to it.

Comment: For a text file, use File.ReadAllText (to get all the text in the file as a single string) or File.ReadAllLines (to get all the text in the file into an array of strings, one element per line in the file).

Comment: I'm aware about reading a file, but i don't understand why i can rename an assembly which is executed, but not rename a file which has a handle on it. both actions should change only the directory entries of the effective file.

Comment: @Manuel Check my answer, I believe that, after some investigation, I found why you can or not.

Comment: You can see the exact answer here (Read the comments too): http://superuser.com/a/488130