# Why can't I replace running .Net assemblies which are loaded by running processes by renaming them on certain computers?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

When I am trying to patch a server with .Net processes running, MSI and other applications can usually [rename the running assemblies to place new ones in the same location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774099/why-does-rename-a-loaded-net-assembly-work).

On one server, I can't:  When using MSI on this computer, restarts are required.  In File Explorer, attempts to rename the files results in a sharing violation.  The same app running on the same OS and antivirus on a different machine is able to be patched in place without issue.

> The action cannot be completed because the file is open in App.exe
>
> Close the file and try again.
>
> [Try Again] [Cancel]

Comparing the open handles using Sysinternals Process Explorer shows that the process is taking a "File" lock on each assembly on the server in question.

Why can't I replace the running file while the process is running on this server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to ensure that Fusion logging is not enabled.  Enabling Fusion logging can result in the application opening a file handle with `FILE_SHARE_READ`.

Fusion logging is controlled by values in the  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion` key.  Running the below `.reg` file will disable fusion logging.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion]
"ForceLog"=dword:00000000
"LogFailures"=dword:00000000
"EnableLog"=dword:00000000
```